# How to make frame decorations bigger?

Tags: lyx, decorations, frame

It is very small and often I can't see them. For instance, those tildes:

[image]

```
\tilde{g}_{ij}\de{\tilde{x}^{i}}{x^{k}}\de{\tilde{x}^{j}}{x^{l}}
```

Comment: How did you typeset that? Please share your code. A minimal example.

Comment: \tilde , but the issue here is that any frame decoration is relatively small.

Comment: I would be more concerned about the tilde to be honest. But as long as you do not share your code with a minimal example, nobody can help you in a good way.

Comment: You mean that code?

Comment: No, I mean a complete (but minimal) document. How should people know how you are making your frame?

Comment: And where can I put it?

Comment: You can paste the code in the box, and then you can mark it and hit the {} button, and it will be marked as code. Try it out, and somebody here will help to edit if you cannot get it right. But remember, _minimal_ complete example.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually very necessary for a question to include an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

I'm a GOM (Grumpy Old Man) and had to waste my time trying to make one up to try and answer your problem.

```
 % tildeprob.tex  SE 637920

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\Huge

Without tildes
\[
g_{ij} \frac{\delta x^i}{\delta x^k} \frac{\delta x^j}{\delta x^l}
\]

With tildes
\[
\tilde{g}_{ij} \frac{\delta \tilde{x}^i}{\delta x^k} \frac{\delta \tilde{x}^j}{\delta x^l}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I just had to assume that you were not using the `\tilde` macro properly.

Following your comment to your question, by "frame decoration" do you mean "Math Mode Accents" as listed by Leslie Lamport in the LaTeX book?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in LyX's workarea display that will be fixed whenever 2.4.0 is released. You can see the reports here:

https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11875

https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11491

Here is the display in LyX 2.3.x:

[image]

And here is the dispaly in LyX 2.4.0dev:

[image]

A workaround would be to turn on instant preview: In Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Display, set "Instant Preview" to "On".

Comment: Much better! Thank you.